# What does it mean "The tensor's graph is different from the session's graph."

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to run this very simple tensorflow code I found on colab, but it seems I'm missing something basic about it.

I already tried to replace xy_sum.eval() with xy_sum.eval(session=sess) but the problem seems to persist.
Here's "my" code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import tensorflow as tf
g=tf.Graph()
with g.as_default():
    x=tf.constant(8,name="x_const")
    y=tf.constant(5,name="y_const")
    xy_sum=tf.add(x,y,name="x_y_sum")
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(xy_sum.eval())
```

I expect the output to be 13 as shown on https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/mlcc/tensorflow_programming_concepts.ipynb#scrollTo=Md8ze8e9geMi,
but the ouput i get from spyder is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-35-67314fd48aa4>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/home/***/.config/spyder-py3/New Folder/sommatf.py', wdir='/home/***/.config/spyder-py3/New Folder')

  File "/home/***/python3.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 786, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/home/***/python3.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/home/***/.config/spyder-py3/New Folder/sommatf.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(xy_sum.eval())

  File "/home/***/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 695, in eval
    return _eval_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)

  File "/home/***/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 5172, in _eval_using_default_session
    raise ValueError("Cannot use the default session to evaluate tensor: "

ValueError: Cannot use the default session to evaluate tensor: the tensor's graph is different from the session's graph. Pass an explicit session to `eval(session=sess)`.
```

if I try, as suggested, to pass an explicit session I get:

```
raise ValueError("Cannot use the given session to evaluate tensor: "

ValueError: Cannot use the given session to evaluate tensor: the tensor's graph is different from the session's graph.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TensorFlow Error found in Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33785936/tensorflow-error-found-in-tutorial)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tf.Session` uses the default graph. So in order to use the graph `g` you would either have to indent the session initialization into the `with g.as_default():` block, or pass the graph to the session [at initialization](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#__init__).